# How to use a path listed in a csv and appending to it

Tags: powershell, csv

The csv has a column, Install_Location. I will like to use that Instanll_Location and append to it \temp

I'm having trouble extracting that row of Install_Locations and adding the additional path to it.

```
$Sourcefile = "C:\File.csv"

$StartProperties  = (Import-Csv $Sourcefile)


$Sorted = $StartProperties |select Server_Name, Service_Name, Install_Location | ? Service_Name -like *DISP* | Sort-Object -Property Server_Name
    $Sorted

$TempDumps = "$($_.Install_Location)\temp"
$TempDumps
```

```
cmdlet DumpCleanup at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Server_Name: TEST

Server_Name   Service_Name                      Install_Location                            
-----------   ------------                      ----------------                            
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP03:9300  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP03
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP09:9900  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP09
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP04:9400  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP04
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP05:9500  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP05
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP06:9600  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP06
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP07:9700  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP07
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP08:9800  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP08
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP02:9200  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP02
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP01:9100  D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP01
DEFRCOGAPP101 IBM Cognos Analytics DISP10:10000 D$\Program Files\ibm\cognos\analytics\DISP10
```

Answer (score 1):

There's tons of information regarding that subject on the internet.

[This article](https://tommymaynard.com/use-powershell-to-edit-a-csv-2017/) basically tells you exactly what you need to do, it's the first one you find when you google for "edit csv PowerShell"

You need to do the following steps:

- Import the CSV
- loop through the CSV
- Change a parameter depending on a condition, or in your case just add to it
- return the whole object
- Export it

Here's the code that follows these steps. Attention: it will overwrite the source CSV. If you don't want to overwrite it, specify another path in `Export-CSV`

```
$CSV = "C:\File.csv"
@(Import-Csv $CSV) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Install_Location += "\temp"
    $_
} | Export-Csv $CSV -Force -NoTypeInformation
```